Transforming the Frequency of Time Series Data
Please I have a challenge that I need your insights on.
I am going to be running a time series analysis on a set of datasets:
CDS spreads, GDP  and other macro economic datasets are in Monthly frequency
ND-GAINS climate index is in annual (2008 to 2019).
what is the best way to resample the ND-GAINS dataset to monthly frequency without introducing spurious data?
I have read the Panda article on upsampling but I am not entirely convinced.
https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/pandas-resample-asfreq

There's no one size fits all interpolation or resampling technique. There are multiple resampling techniques like linear, average, min, max or window approaches. you will have to share more about the dataset here, for example plots to perhaps get a better understanding of the nature of data.
Or maybe I'm understanding your question wrong and you just want sample code to resample from year to months?

Finally, after spending some on Rpubs, CRAN and following the references that have quoted the paper of Chow and Lin, we have the best solution: Temporal Disaggregation of Time Series by Christoph Sax and Peter Steiner using the R package ‘tempdisagg’
The package tempdisagg (Sax and Steiner, 2013) is an extension of the standard methods for temporal disaggregation developed by all earlier researchers that I have read their works: Denton, Denton-Cholette, Chow-Lin, Fernandez and Litterman.
